# How can i make a proper if/else if/else statement?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create a game in Unity for my game development class using c#. I'm having a problem trying to make an input statement. What i would like it to do is if i input for example "1", i want it to respond (for now) "you chose 1!"  but it is not playing it. If it helps I'm using this for my game.

Here is what i have so far

```
void UserInput(string input)
    {
        if (input == "1")
        {
            print("You choose 1");
        }
        else if (input == "2")
        {
            print("You choose 2");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Invalid Response");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Edit: Thank you all for helping me. I'm very new to all of this. I appreciate all of the responses

Comment: The best way to solve your problem is to use the [integrated debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019). You will discover in no time that your input is not what you think.

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question. I doubt anyone is going to request permission to the file you linked, and they shouldn't be expected to.

Comment: Its also worth noting that in this case, a switch statement or strategy pattern is much better for code clarity and isolation.

Answer (score 3):

If your output what was input, perhaps you might be able to spot the problem:

```
void UserInput(string input)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"The input was '{input}'");
```

The single quotes are useful when the input is empty, because then you will see `The input was ''` rather than `The input was`.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you seem to only want to inform the end-user of their input, in which case you can simply do:

```cs
public void UserInput(string input) {
    Console.WriteLine($"You choose {input}");
}
```

However, if you only wish to handle certain cases (in your case, only 1 and 2), then you can use a switch statement:

```cs
public void UserInput(string input) {
    switch(input) {
        case "1":
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine($"You choose {input}"); // will only write 1 or 2
            break; // necessary to prevent fall-through
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Response");
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is

```
void UserInput(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Response");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"You choose {input}");
        }
```